# Asking for a raise higher than the pre-allocated one

Tags: negotiation, raise

My contract states that my salary in the following year will be X, which is a ~6% monthly increase from the current one. 
When the time comes to renew the contract (which is shortly from now), I want to ask for a higher raise than the one stated.

The work environment is relaxed and I have a good relationship with my supervisor. I've done well on the tasks I've had, but it's not like I've made any breakthroughs that will lift the company up. Up until now I haven't had any tasks where I was pressured on the deadline. However, I'm about to take over a project where I was working solo on. The future of this project looks promising for the company.

Are there any drawbacks to asking for a higher salary when the renewal of the contract comes?

Comment: Drawbacks for asking? No. Successfully getting it? Also probably No. BTW, there are several similar questions on asking for more salary in this forum.

Comment: @PagMax I saw posts on negotiating for a higher salary before getting the job, or asking for a raise in the current job; but didn't see any question of my type.

Comment: @PagMax why do you think there are no drawbacks?

Comment: Some good tips in the answers here for the raise conversation itself: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025/5652

Comment: @Antonio. Well if you politely ask once without pestering them, they can either agree or just say No professionally and move on.  I do not see any drawbacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should always negotiate your compensation if you feel you are being underpaid.** The worst that can reasonably happen is your employer offering what you have already agreed to (in your case, the 6% raise).

You can maximize your chances of improving your raise if you:

1. **Have a specific level of compensation ready** when you approach your manager. E.g., "Next year, I'm looking for $_____ in salary."
2. **Provide a clear reason why your previous compensation is no longer appropriate.** E.g., "My responsibilities have substantially grown since I started." or "Raises for my role at other companies tend to be __%."
3. **Know what you would accept if offered.** Don't push a negotiation to the point of being inflexible and uncooperative. If your employer makes a counter-offer, know ahead of time what level of compensation you would be excited to receive, even if less than your initial request. Think about alternatives to cash compensation as well (e.g., more time off).

Good luck in the discussion!

Comment: I would suggest softening the "Raises for my role at other companies tend to be __%." comment, especially as OP has a good relationship with their current company. It could come across as a threat to leave!